# Access Denied when calling the PutObject operation - AWS Lambda Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

This is the first time i am working with AWS. I am trying to create a CICD Pipeline for a basic hello world python code.

Git hub integration, change detection is working fine in AWS Code Pipeline but during the **build** stage, i am getting this error again and again.

**ERROR:**
*Unable to upload artifact . referenced by CodeUri parameter of app resource.An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied*

**Here are the details with respect to my project.**

Github (for Python Code, buildspec.yaml and template.yaml files) -
https://github.com/prahamurali/awscicd.git

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrFlL.jpg)

[IAM Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54EjB.jpg)

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF2wR.jpg)

[S3 Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vp29.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it is unclear which role is shown in `IAM Roles`. However, it seems to be the role not associated with **CodeBuild**.

If this is the case, then you need to add S3 access permissions to the role of your **CodeBuild project**, not CodePipeline nor CloudFormation. The reason is that CodeBuild is the service that will be actually uploading your objects to S3, thus it needs such permissions.

Comment: You were right. Thank you. I had my Code Build role edited to have the required S3 permissions and it worked smoothly. I was able to get my Lambda Deployed. But it wasnt named as i needed. It had a random name appended to the Changeset like "SampleCICD-Stack-app-MG8SDD6FFMF7" where "SampleCICD-Stack" is the Stack name and "app" is my local lambda name. How can i name my Lambda while the deployment is in progress ?

Comment: @PrahaMurali No problem. Glad it worked out. You can use  [FunctionName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-functionname) in your SAM template.